# How to get exact word using angular filter pipe and not words matching the value?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

Example if i search [App] i don't want to see [Apple, Appliance, Appliances], instead i want to only see [App] in the search

```
    @Pipe({
    name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any, filter: any, isAnd: bool): any {
    if (filter && Array.isArray(items)) {
      let filterKeys = Object.keys(filter);
      if (isAnd) {
        return items.filter(item =>
            filterKeys.reduce((memo, keyName) =>
                (memo && new RegExp(filter[keyName], 'gi').test(item[keyName])) || filter[keyName] === "", true));
      } else {
        return items.filter(item => {
          return filterKeys.some((keyName) => {
            console.log(keyName);
            return new RegExp(filter[keyName], 'gi').test(item[keyName]) || filter[keyName] === "";
          });
        });
      }
    } else {
      return items;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: worth a read: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe I would first of all suggest you handle this in the component, like the angular team also recommends.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing `new RegExp(filter[keyName], 'gi').test(item[keyName]))`, you will need to do `filter[keyName] === item[keyName]`. I hope this helps

Comment: No that didn't work sadly, what i changed was the following:

(memo && (filter[keyName] === item[keyName])) || filter[keyName] === "", true))

Comment: have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think with this code is success

```
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any, filter: any, isAnd: bool): any {
    if (filter && Array.isArray(items)) {
      return filter.map(filterItem => items.filter(itemItem => itemItem === filterItem).join())
    } else {
      return items;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I get filter.map is not a function error when using that

Comment: filter is the name to variable an I suppose is other array, if is a string is more easy :)

Comment: So if it was a string it would not need filter.map?

Comment: if you pass as string, only need items.filter(itemItem => itemItem === filter)

Comment: Neither one of those work sadly, have any other idea?

Comment: can you share an example how do you implement and what is the final label that you expect